# How to adjust a FlowDocuments fontsize relative to its container?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument inside a FlowDocumentScrollViewer.
The size of the container changes.
So does the size of images in the FlowDocument:

```
<Paragraph>
    <Image Source="/InnovationsforumInfoterminal;component/res/wohnzimmer.jpg"></Image>-->
</Paragraph>
```

The text-size however always stays the same:

```
<Paragraph FontFamily="Arial">
    Die beiden wichtigsten ...
</Paragraph>
```

I want the whole document to scale with the container (so the displayed text, images always look the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is set to strech... try changing the image as follows:

```
<Paragraph>    
   <Image 
       Source="/InnovationsforumInfoterminal;component/res/wohnzimmer.jpg"
       Strecth="None">
   </Image>
</Paragraph>
```

Comment: In that case nothing stretches anymore.
The container just gets bigger. How do I stretch the whole content?